# Resources on Wolstenholme's theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients

In Wikipedia entry on Wolstenholme's theorem, it says

`The second formulation $\binom{ap}{bp}=\binom{a}{b}\pmod{p^3}$ of Wolstenholme's theorem is due to J. W. L. Glaisher.`

But there is no reference to it. Does anyone know which paper of J. W. L. Glaisher contains the above statement?

Comment: Did you try Dickson's "Theory of Numbers"?

Comment: ...or Google: the first Google hit for **glaisher wolstenholme** is
<http://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.3057.pdf>, where
on page 25 there are three references ([32] to [34]) 
to papers by Glaisher published in the *Q.J.Math.* in 1900 or 1901;
the second of these ("On the residues of the sums of products of the first 
$p - 1$ numbers, and their powers, to modulus $p^2$ or $p^3$")
seems particularly promising.


Comment: Thanks. I have added these references to the Wikipedia page.